# PHP calling python script and button disappear after clicked in php

Tags: php, html

i have a python script, that can be called from PHP

start.php

```
    <html>
 <body>
   <form method="post">

    <input type="submit" value="Start" name="GO">
   </form>
 </body>
</html>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['GO']))
    {
        shell_exec("sudo python3 /start.py");
    }
?>
```

how do I make the button disappear if the service is running already?
or make a popup windows saying its already running when user tried to click again?

i have another php where it can check the service running or not

status.php

```
<?php
exec("ps aux | grep -v grep | grep  sudo", $psOutput);
if (count($psOutput) > 0) {
    echo "RUNNING";
}
else{
    echo "not running";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to disable the button by adding below code

```
<input type='submit' <?php if(count($psOutput) > 0) {?> disabled="disabled" <?php } ?> name='GO' value='Start' >
```

maybe it will help someone else.